# How to disable built-in keypress actions in Angular Material?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-material

I have a trouble with Angular Material's sidenav's native hotkey 'esc' action. When the esc is pressed, the framework will toggle `$mdSidenav('left/right').toggle()`. This is undesirable because I want my toggle action to also toggle other actions.

I have tried using "pure" javascript to block the action with codes:

```
document.onkeydown = function(e) {
    if (e.which == 27) return false;
};

document.onkeyup = function(e) {
    if (e.which == 27) return false;
};
```

It failed. And I tired:

```
document.onkeydown = function(e) {
  if (e.which == 27) {
    break;
    return false;
  }
};

document.onkeyup = function(e) {
  if (e.which == 27) {
    break;
    return false;
  }
};
```

It also failed because it's not a legal break statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can disable the esc action by removing the line 93 in `angular-material.js`.

Answer (score 0):

Following this aproach: https://github.com/angular/material/issues/974#issuecomment-67784785

You could watch on `$scope.isOpen` and when it is closed you can check (with another scope flag) if your "Close" button was pressed. If not, you can reopen the sidenav and it will not be perceived by the user.

Hope it helps.